# How can I massively download files (with a filter) from a remote directory from FileZilla

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, filezilla

I have connection to a remote server in FileZilla. So far I am able to download massively every file of the directory, but is huge and contains much other files than needed.

How can I download the files that comply with the condition "begin with..."?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a Directory listing filter (in *View* menu).

The filter is followed even during transfers.

A slight disadvantage is, that the filter is a permanent setting. So you have to go back after the transfer and unset it. The filter is also relatively complex to setup.

---

If you prefer a temporary-style filter for transfers, you probably have to use another client.

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), the [filter is part of transfer settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom). In WinSCP (while permanent presets are also possible), you can setup an ad-hoc settings (including a filter) for each transfer.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*